# Gnosis safe transfer function `Approve Hash` but does not transfer erc20 token

Tags: ethers.js, gnosis-safe, ethereum-classic, address.transfer, gnosis

I am using the gnosis-safe core SDK here to create transactions to transfer Eth out of a deployed safe proxy. Doc: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#deploysafe

I deployed the proxy on Rinkeby via:

```
        const { ethereum } = window;
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum)
        const safeOwner = provider.getSigner(0)
        const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({ ethers, signer: safeOwner });

        const txServiceUrl = 'https://safe-transaction.gnosis.io';
        const safeService = new SafeServiceClient({ txServiceUrl, ethAdapter });
        const is_dev = true;
        let ethAdapter = this.ethAdapter;
        const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter, isL1SafeMasterCopy: !is_dev });

        const safeAccountConfig = {
          owners: ['0x...D9'],
          threshold: 1,
        }        

        const safeSdk = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig });
```

So it is a safe with just one authorizer. I then deposit some ETH into this safe proxy, and try to send it out of the safe with:

```
        let safeAddress = '0x...c';
        const safeSdk = await Safe.create({ ethAdapter, safeAddress, isL1SafeMasterCopy: false })
        const num_ethers = ethers.utils.parseUnits("0.1", 'ether').toHexString();
        const transaction = {
          to: '0x...1', 
          data: '0x',
          value:num_ethers,
        }
        const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(transaction)        
        console.log('safeTransaction: ', safeTransaction)
        const hash = await safeSdk.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
        const txResponse = await safeSdk.approveTransactionHash(hash);
        const reshash = await txResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();
```

What ends up happening is that the authorizer is charged for the `ApproveHash` transaction, but the Eth does not transfer. Is there something I'm missing here conceptually? The data field should be `0x` for transferring eth on Rinkeby network as well right? Tx log here: https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x99Ae62C23728EAa970F5064DcD3F869ae80FC89c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`approveTransactionHash` only approves the transaction without executing it. Please refer to the core SDK documentation to learn how to execute a transaction https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/guides/integrating-the-safe-core-sdk.md#8-execute-the-transaction

Comment: Ok following that documentation, but I'm getting stuck at step 5. Propose the transaction to the service
: I am getting error: `POST https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io/api/v1/safes/0x07fa8876c390066B80B8735D98210822dBF32f5C/multisig-transactions/ 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
sendRequest @ httpRequests.ts:16
proposeTransaction @ SafeServiceClient.ts:392
await in proposeTransaction (async)
GnosisAPI.propose_tx @ gnosis_api.js:364
httpRequests.ts:52 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unprocessable Entity`  It seems like the API is not POSTING with correct params

Comment: ^-- note in this case I deployed a safe proxy with two keys and threshold=2, so I need to propose a transaction with `await safeService.proposeTransaction({...})` so the 2nd signer can retrieve the tx, and sign it.

Comment: i resolved this question, and posted a follow up question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/131297/gnosis-safe-getting-unprocessable-entity-error-when-proposing-a-transaction-t